# Check if A ListTemplate is hidden using Sharepoint web services

Tags: web-services

I am currently using Sharepoint web services in order to retrive information about some Lists and ListItems.

My problem is about specifically dealing with hidden Lists i.e. lists whoe `SPListTemplate.Hidden` is `True`. Refer [documentation for SPListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplate_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Using the Sharepoint server object model, it is possible to check if a `SPListTemplate` is hidden. However, the XML fragment returned by `Webs.GetListTemplates()` by following the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getlisttemplates%28v=office.12%29.aspx) does not get information on whether the `SPListTemplate` is hidden or not.

I have verified within my application that the XML fragment we receive is exactly as what is mentioned in the documentation for `Webs.GetListTemplates()`..

Hence my question - how can I use the existing Microsoft Sharepoint web services to figure out if a list template is hidden or not?

Also the solution should be agnostic to the Sharepoint server versions (SP2007/2010/2013/Office Online)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did quite some research on this and figured out that the only way we can do this is by writing our own web service which resides on Sharepoint and would expose a method that performs the calculation on Sharepoint server using the Server Object model and returns a boolean result stating whether the list is hidden or not

Comment: Can you post the code by updating the answer